# How to copy dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python script which does the following:

```
final_df = main_df
final_df['new_column'] = final_df['b']*0.05
```

Basically I don't want to disturb `main_df` dataframe and work on a copy of it. But when run the above script, both `final_df` and `main_df` affect in similar ways. Why does this happen?

If I want to achieve the required way, how do I proceed?

Comment: ``final_df = main_df.copy()`` that way main_df is not affected

Comment: `final_df = main_df` *never makes a copy*

Answer (score 2):

use [copy](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) method:

```
final_df = main_df.copy()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to *deep copy* it other wise it would be pointing to the same object.
So it would be

```
final_df = main_df.copy() # by default deep copy is done
```

Here is the [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is when you do `final_df = main_df`, a copy of `main_df` is not made but just a new reference `final_df` is created thereby both `final_df` and `main_df` referring to the same memory location. So if one is changed like `final_df` in your case, the changes are also reflected into `main_df` as both are pointing to same memory location.
Example:

```
main_df = ['final', 'df']
final_df = main_df
print (f'Location of final_df: {id(final_df)}')
print (f'Location of main_df: {id(main_df)}')
```

Both the above `print` statements will print the same memory location.
[Here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) is the nice writeup to understand this behavior.
If you don't want your `main_df` not to be affected, create a deepcopy of it as below:

```
final_df = main_df.copy()
```

with `copy()` a complete new copy is created and can be verified with below code:

```
from copy import copy
main_df = ['final', 'df']
final_df = main_df.copy()
print (f'Location of final_df: {id(final_df)}')
print (f'Location of main_df: {id(main_df)}')
```

Now both the `print` statements will print 2 different memory locations.